# Installing Cairo on Mac - Could not find libpng in the pkg-config search path

Tags: macos, bash, cairo, libpng

> checking whether cairo's PNG functions feature could be enabled... no

I have been following the setup for configuring node canvas. Cairo is needed but i am having issues trying to set it up. https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---OSX

> If libpng fails and you get the error "error: recommended PNG functions feature could not be enabled", try installing this binary and re-running the configure step.

I followed above by installing the binaries on Mac OS 9 and run the configuration command and still no luck. I am running the install shell script in node-canvas repository:

https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/master/install

In my /usr/local/lib I currently have:

```
dtrace          libjpeg.8.dylib     libpng.a        libpng14.a
libfreetype.6.dylib libjpeg.a       libpng.dylib        libpng14.dylib
libfreetype.a       libjpeg.dylib       libpng.la       libpng14.la
libfreetype.dylib   libjpeg.la      libpng12.0.dylib    libpng15.15.dylib
libfreetype.la      libpixman-1.0.dylib libpng12.0.dylib.dSYM   libpng15.15.dylib.dSYM
libgif.4.1.6.dylib  libpixman-1.a       libpng12.a      libpng15.a
libgif.4.dylib      libpixman-1.dylib   libpng12.dylib      libpng15.dylib
libgif.a        libpixman-1.la      libpng12.la     libpng15.la
libgif.dylib        libpng.3.dylib      libpng14.14.dylib   node_modules
libgif.la       libpng.3.dylib.dSYM libpng14.14.dylib.dSYM  pkgconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Libpng-1.6.10 has been replaced by libpng-1.6.12.

In your install script, change

```
LIBPNG="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng16/1.6.10/libpng-1.6.10.tar.gz"
```

to

```
LIBPNG="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng16/1.6.12/libpng-1.6.12.tar.gz"
```

Comment: After the change, is libpng16.* still missing from /usr/local/lib?

Answer (score 0):

I have a set of detailed instructions for building cairo here:

```
https://github.com/soegaard/racket-osx-libs
```

There resulting libraries are here:

```
https://github.com/soegaard/racket-osx-libs/tree/master/lib
```